# does file_get_contents search the source code or inspect element?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

When you use file_get_contents in php, is the content that it gets the source code of the site, or what you would seen if you were to use inspect element in chrome? Thanks.

Comment: If you're using file_get_contents() with a URL, it retrieves the markup that is generated by that site, as you'd get if you went to that URL in a web browser then did a view source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to get whatever you are able to get. For local files, it will read the content of the file, whatever that is. `file_get_contents('foo.php')` will get you some PHP source code. `file_get_contents('bar.jpg')` will get you the raw bytes of a JPEG file.

For remote URLs it's going to get whatever any regular client will get. `file_get_contents('http://google.com')` gives you the same HTML that a browser sees when visiting that page.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to give you the source of whatever resource you're accessing. But this is for **file access**. If you use it on a remote resource such as a web URL, you're going to get the processed result. E.g. if you retrieve something from another PHP site such as www.example.com, methinks you'll be looking at the "source" from whatever the PHP server processed and served up - not the actual source code itself but rather the fully processed form of the accessed page (just like hitting "view source" in a browser).

> If you're looking to retrieve that kind of data remotely I'd strongly
>   suggest using wget, as I'm not even sure that file_get_contents works
>   remotely.

Never mind that - per one of the first items in the [file_get_contents documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) you can use URIs.